# Why does my code not insert a new node into this linked list?

Tags: c, linked-list, append, singly-linked-list

I am new to programming. I just want to know why this doesn't work.
My understanding of pointers isn't clear, especially when using pointers across functions.

```
void append(struct Node** head_ref, float new_data)
{

    struct Node* new_node = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    struct Node *last = *head_ref;  /* used in step 5*/


    new_node->data  = new_data;
    new_node->next = NULL;

    while (last != NULL)
        last = last->next;


    last = new_node;
    return;
}

void append(struct Node** head_ref, float new_data)
{

while (last->next != NULL)
        last = last->next;


    last->next = new_node;
    return;
}
```

In the first function the new data doesn't get included, I get only the original linked list.

But the second function works just fine. How does a double pointer work when inserting a new node in the beginning of the linked list? (I have seen answers regarding this question, but I am still confused)

Comment: What is the value of last when you exit each loop?

Comment: The second `append` function as it stands in your question can't compile because `last` is declared nowhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the local variable `last` does not change the value of the data member `next` of the previous (last) node.

To be more clear let's assume that the list is empty. Then you have to change the pointer referenced by this double pointer `head_ref`.
You declared a new pointer

```
struct Node *last = *head_ref;
```

The loop

```
while (last != NULL)
    last = last->next;
```

is skipped because now already last is equal to NULL die to the  initialization in the previous declaration. And then you changed this local variable `last`

```
last = new_node;
```

The original value of the pointer pointed by `head_ref` was not changed because `last` and `*head_ref` occupy different extents of memory. You changed the memory occupied by `last` but not changed the memory occupied by `head_ref`.

Also you should check whether a memory was successfully allocated.

The function can look the following way

```
int append( struct Node **head_ref, float new_data )
{
    struct Node *new_node = malloc( sizeof( struct Node ) );
    int success = new_node != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        new_node->data  = new_data;
        new_node->next  = NULL;

        while ( *head_ref != NULL ) head_ref = &( *head_ref )->next;

        *head_ref = new_node;
    }

    return success;
}
```

As for this loop (I think you wanted just to show the loop not a whole function)

```
while (last->next != NULL)
        last = last->next;


    last->next = new_node;
```

then you are changing the data member `next` of the previous (last ) node.

Though this loop will not work if initially `head_ref` is equal to `NULL`.

Comment: thanks for the answer......i have a question about your modified code.....`while ( *head_ref != NULL ) head_ref = &( *head_ref )->next;`instead of this when i use this `while ( *head_ref != NULL ) *head_ref = *head_ref ->next;` which i think should have worked but doesnt.....can you please tell me why the second code doesnt work.....

Comment: @RJRuhan The postfix operator -> has a higher priority than the unary operator *. So without parentheses the expression look like *( head_ref->next )

Answer (score 3):

In the first example, you move the pointer `last` until it points at a `NULL` location. Then, you set the pointer to `new_node`. However, at this point, `last` has no real association to your linked list. It is just a pointer to some memory. In the second example, the correct one, you iterate until you reach the tail of the linked list, where `next` of that node is `NULL`. Then, you set that `next` to `new_node`. There is now a new tail to the list, that is `new_node`.